# Visual Studio: Compile hdrstop-precompiled header only when necessary

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm using the Visual Studio compiler on the command line. I build from a batch file that calls `cl.exe` twice. The first call creates the PCH with the `/Yc` option (without a file name argument), and the second uses the PCH with the `/Yu` option. I have only one source file where I use `pragma hdrstop`.

Now, when I don't change the code before the `hdrstop`, it is unnecessary for the compiler to do anything on the first call. How can I tell `cl.exe` to just skip compilation if nothing changed?

Comment: It is the job of a build system to figure out if the compiler *must* run because .h or .cpp files changed.  Running cl.exe from the command line is the antipode of using a build system.  More than one way to do this, using msbuild.exe is the most obvious path to success.  Or just plain use the IDE and just press Ctrl+Shift+B, this is meant to be simple.

Answer (score 0):

You normally don't do that in the compiler.   Instead, you use a makefile that avoids calling the compiler if nothing changed.

If you create a project inside the Visual Studio IDE, it will figure out all of those dependencies automatically.  You can even export a make file if you really want to.  Or, instead of calling cl, call visual studio from the command line with command line options set to build, not bring up the IDE.